# Use of kbhit() with while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, turbo-c, kbhit

Here is the program.

```
void main( )
{
    int h, v;
    h = 1; v = 10;
    while ( !kbhit( ) || h <= 80 )
    {
        gotoxy( h, v );
        printf( "<--->" );
        delay( 200 );
        clrscr( );
        h = h + 1;
    }
    getch( );
}
```

I am making a program in C, in which I have used `kbhit()` to run a loop until a key is pressed.
so here the arrow `"<--->"` will keep on moving forward until a key is pressed or until it reaches the last pixel of the screen.

What I want is that the program should increment h by 1 everytime `'d'` is pressed and decrement by 1 everytime `'a'` is pressed. i.e  `h++;` and `h--;`
and run another loop until a character is pressed.
The idea is more like the Snake game, in which the snake keeps on moving in a certain direction until a key is pressed. Help please!

Comment: With what are you compiling that?

Comment: Sorry "clrscr();]" is a typo.

Comment: With turbo C complier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clrscr() should come before the gotoxy and printf

Anyway, what I would do is create a state variable, just to indicate the direction the snake should go, i.e., something that stores if the user pressed 'a' or 'd'.

And I would not leave the loop, just use a if(kbhit) and get the char.

```
int direction = 1; char control;
while (1)
{
    if(kbhit()){
       control = getch();
       switch (control){
              case 'a': direction = -1; break;
              case 'd': direction = +1; break;
              default: break;
       }
    }
    clrscr( );
    gotoxy( h, v );
    printf( "<--->" );
    delay( 200 );
    h = h + direction;
}
```

Comment: Forgot your screen boundaries, but you can easily put that in the while loop (and yes, while(1) is not very elegant).

Comment: Thanks @ThoAppelsin, you're right. And back to the original question, if you're planning on building a snake game, you'll have a hard time when you add the vertical movement. The best way to implement a snake game I believe is through linked lists

Comment: It worked.Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.Yeah I will put that screen boundries , no problem.Putting while (control!='q') instead of while (1) looks more promising, if user want to quit all he/she has to do is press 'q'.Thanks again man!