# Do something when i press a certain key?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

How do i make the program to recognize the certain keys I press?
To understand the context: I want to make a game in C (very basic game), so in order to move the object, I want to pres (W A S D),I know how to move it, but I don't know how to make the program understand that I want to do a certain action, when one of those keys are pressed.
For example:

```
if( key == "A"){
x++
}
```

I know it dose not work like that, but something at least similar.

Comment: You can use graphics.h

Comment: the keyword is `fgetc`. search it.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to poll if a key is pressed, fire an event when one is pressed or hang your program and wait for the enter key to be pressed?

Comment: How about `kbhit()` in `conio.h` (if you have it), or this Linux [implementation](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/_kbhit_for_Linux.shtml) of it.

Comment: @TahaPaksu `fgetc` will not help with this.

Comment: @melpomene I understood the question wrong then.

Comment: Which operating system and which compiler are you using?

Comment: `wasd` controls and console applications don't go well together.

Comment: Windows 7, visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> /* getch() and kbhit() */

int main()
{
    char c;

    for(;;){
        if(kbhit()){
            c = getch();
            if(c == 'c')
            {
                printf("%c\n", c);

               // more code here..
            }
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

as the above answer, but the code must be in infinite loop to scan whenever a key is pressed. and the code will only check if the key 'c' is pressed. you can easily remove the if condition and make it more generalized  :)

Comment: How do I make it to print, just when c key is pressed? right know it prints any key I press .

Comment: what do you want to print?

Comment: if you dont want to print the key pressed remove ` printf("%c\n", c);` and add other code. :)

Comment: Well let's say when i press C key it will print "C key was pressed" but if i press any other key, it should not print.

Comment: just check if the char c is "C" or Not.! by using if(c == 'c'){ //code here   } :)

Comment: `getch()` returns `int` not `char`.

Comment: dont forget to make it as answer and upvote :) happy to help :D

Comment: you can always check a char with an int @alk

Answer (score 1):

You can include `conio.h` (on Windows) or `ncurses.h` libraries (on Linux) and using functions like `getch()` for return a char that is pressed by the user. Then you can check if the char is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kbhit` included in `conio.h` as mentioned in the comments above.A simple example is shown below.

```
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;

    if (kbhit()) {

            // Stores the pressed key in ch
            ch = getch();
            printf("%c was pressed.\n", ch)

            //do something..

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270310/use-of-kbhit-with-while-loop) will be helpful to you.